Landsat 8 C2 L2 FOR NDVI
When I download Landsat 8 C2 L2 image from USGS and apply directly NDVI formula the value is ok it is in range -1,+1 while where I am applying scale factor which is (0.0000275)-(0.2) for each band then calculating the NDVI the range exceed from -1,and +1.
Do I need apply scale factor for C2 L2? I am using ArcGIS Pro and ArcGIS and tool that I used Band arithmetic mean which contain many type of index in ArcGIS Pro, and I use different times the issue still same.
